# What is the difference between the command that yarn run [dev] executes and its vanilla node implementation?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

This is my package.json file. As you can see it has a dev command that I can execute with **yarn dev** [image: Package.json]

I figured that if I copy the command that yarn dev would run which is  **node .electron-nuxt/dev.js --inspect** I would be able to run the command outside of yarn (to attach the script to my debugger with node). But when I copied that exact command, it produced no errors and did nothing. Why does **yarn dev** work but not **node .electron-nuxt/dev.js --inspect** if they point to the same piece of code?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of how npm/yarn locate executable files. It's called mode of operation and it's basically how these package managers resolve and execute modules.

While both behave somehow differently, the underlying operation is still similar. There are two modes local and global. the package manager tries to resolve the module in local mode first; that's from the directory where you run the script. If it didn't find it then it tries to resolve it from the global scope.

So to answer your question, yarn execute the file from the global scope.

- Resources

[How node resolves modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) Node.js docs

[The node_modules problem](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp#the-node_modules-problem) Yarn docs